# Find first two records from collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to retrieve the first two records from collection such that, collection is like:

```
@collect_firstnames = @name.firstnames
```

From this collection I want to fetch first two records...

I used limit it is not working, `:limit => 2`

Comment: You should post some code so we can see what you tried.

Answer (score 4):

I take it that `@name.firstnames` is a `has_many` relationship. You need to pass the options to `all`:

```
@name.firstnames.all(:limit => 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the :limit option like this:

```
@first_two = Name.find(:all, :limit => 2)
```

**Edit**

It's the same idea, assuming firstnames is a relationship (just like Swanand said below)

```
@first_two = @name.firstnames.all(:limit => 2)
```

Comment: i want to fetch first two from the collection